# How to find the probability that a standard error is with in a specific amount for a normal distribution?

Tags: r, probability

I am trying to find the CLT(Central Limit Theorem) approximation that the probability of the standard error is equal or larger than 0.01 for a normal distribution?

To calculate the probability that the error is 0.01 or larger

Given:

N= Number of samples is 100

X = The sample average is 0.51

SE = I calculated the standard error by sqrt(X * (1-X)/N)

Then I used the `pnorm()` function.  Please see the code below. When I run the compiler, it gives me an argument error for the `pnorm()` function.

## R code

```
# `N` is the number of people polled
N <-100

# `X` is the sample average
X <- 0.51

# `se` is the standard error of the sample average
se <- sqrt(X*(1-X)/N)

# Calculating the probability that the error is 0.01 or larger
1-(pnorm(0.01/se) - pnorm(-0.01/se))
```

When I run the code, the compiler gives me an argument error for the `pnorm()` function.

Comment: Note that here you test the probability for the **standard** normal distribution, with mean of `0` and `sd` of 1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, this is what I get when I run your code. There isn't an error.

```
> N <-100
> X <- 0.51
> se <- sqrt(X*(1-X)/N)
> 1-(pnorm(0.01/se) - pnorm(-0.01/se))
[1] 0.8414493
```

Comment: Thank you Siong. The computation works. I was trying to find the error in calling the argument for pnorm.